# Node.js MSSQL ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect code: 'ESOCKET'

Tags: node.js, sql-server

my dbconfig.js

```
const config = {
  user: 'sa',
  password: '123456',
  server: '127.0.0.1',
  database: 'sportsxdb',
  options: {
    trustedconnection: true,
    enableArithAbort: true,
    instancename: 'SQLEXPRESS',
  },
  port: 1433,
}


module.exports = config
```

Hi guys, I'm trying to connect to my application's database and it's giving me the following error

Node.js MSSQL  ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect  code: 'ESOCKET'

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Specify an instance name, or specify a port, but don't specify both. Also the [default configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-sql-server-network-protocol-configuration?view=sql-server-ver15#default-configuration) of SQL Server Express edition doesn't have the TCP/IP protocol enabled, so it won't be listening on port 1433.

Comment: If you are doing this on the same machine as SQL Server then use `.` for the server instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, use and `instancename` but no `port`